# React.memo not running at all

Tags: reactjs

I can't get `React.memo` to work - here is a simplified demo of what I'm trying to do

```
import {memo} from 'react'

function BadComponent({a}) {
    return <div>{a}</div>
}

function areEqual(prev,next) {
    console.log('This is never run')
    return prev.a === next.a
}

export default memo(BadComponent, areEqual)
```

Then, in the parent, I run it like this:

```
function Page(){
   const a = 1
   return <BadComponent a={a} />`
}
```

That renders fine. If I use devtools to change prop `a` from 1 to 5 it does not run the `areEqual` function. Example here - https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-frog-f1h9e?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at first mount `areEqual` won't run (*there is no much sense to make a comparison here*). It will execute on subsequent rerenders, triggered by your parent.

if you change your `App` to something like below (adding a state that will trigger a rerender on button click) you will see the console log triggering:

```
export default function App() {
  const [a, setA] = useState(1)
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BadComponent a={a}></BadComponent>
      <button onClick={() => setA(a => a + 1)}>change a</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```